# Lamp energy in BGE does not get higher than 10!

Tags: game-engine, light

Using Blender 2.69. Trying to control lamp strength by setting "own.energy += 1;" in controller script and printing own.energy to console. It works insofar as I can see the lamp changing strength in game mode. However.....
For some reason, the value of own.energy does not get higher than 10! Even if I directly assign 20 or 100 to it! When it starts as 20, as soon as I activate the script it gets back to 10. What can be wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.0 is the limit for lamps. You really should not need it that bright. If you do, consider using a Constant falloff instead of a mathematical fall-off. Maybe adjust world Mist values?
Note also that Sun and Spot are the only lamps that cast shadows. And those start and end values have to be set just so.